# HTML5 - Read the Clipboard?

Tags: html

Is it possible with HTML 5 to read the clipboard (without using Java)?

Comment: The accepted answer for this question should be changed, as it's now out of date.

Answer (score 20):

Perhaps the HTML5 Core spec doesn't provide an API for accessing the clipboard, but one of the APIs in the HTML5 family of APIs does.  It's called "Clipboard API and Events," and its currently (as of July 2011) a Working Draft.  You can find the spec here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/

As for implementations, well, I couldn't find one just yet.

Update:  As of Dec 2012, this API is still a working draft (dated Feb 2012).  There still do not appear to be any working implementations, [just a Flash-based workaround for text](http://pivotallabs.com/users/mrushakoff/blog/articles/2215-you-can-t-yet-programmatically-copy-an-image-to-the-clipboard-from-a-javascript-web-app).

Comment: What?  You think Michael J Fox is the only one with a DeLorean?  :-)

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can use pure JavaScript for this, assuming a modern browser that implements the Clipboard API such as Google Chrome.[Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) is available for IE support and I assume that Firefox will implement the Clipboard API fairly soon. You can only read clipboard data from paste events (such as `Ctrl+V`), but from that you can read binary data such as image data.

[HTML Clipboard API jQuery Plugin and demo](http://strd6.com/2011/09/html5-javascript-pasting-image-data-in-chrome/). This demo requires the Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built-in API for accessing the clipboard. BUT you can use https://github.com/mojombo/clippy for accessing the clipboard. It's flash not Java, so it should be ok for you to use. The advantage is it works across all flash-capable browsers.

Comment: HTML5 has clipboard API, already supported by several major browsers.

Comment: No, this is not correct. There is a clipboard API, but it is only fully supported in Firefox. This again is because it's only a working draft. See here: http://caniuse.com/#search=clipboard

Comment: Also supported by Chrome. But, the fact is you have said "There is no built-in API". That is not true. There is one and several browsers support it.

Comment: You are right with what I said. But the table from: http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard clearly states that Chrome only has partial support for the Clipboard API.